# Python twisted OpenSSL error in Windows

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, twisted, pyopenssl

I am trying to run a twisted script that uses SSL on Windows 7 32bit (Python 2.7.8).  The script works without error under OSX.  I have installed pyOpenSSL via pip and also OpenSSL for Windows, yet when running the application I get:

```
ERROR [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.web
._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived'>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'Op
enSSL.SSL.Error'>>]
]
```

In windows, `"from OpenSSL import SSL"` works fine.  I have searched for a solution without success.  Is there some special configuration that needs to be done to get SSL working with twisted under windows?  Thanks

Comment: Can you please include a minimal script that reproduces this error?

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned:  I'm trying to run the test_client.py script from this project: https://code.google.com/p/py-eas-client/source/checkout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the problem was with twisted.  Pip installed version 14, which is the current release.  I uninstalled and then downgraded to version 13, and now the script is working as expected.  Not sure why, and not planning on looking in to this further for the time being.